# how to pass a variable to *args function parameter

Tags: ruby

I have the following line of code:

```
str.start_with?("str1", "str2", "str3")
```

Is it possible I can pass a variable/list into this function instead? Something like:

```
list_of_strs = ["str1", "str2", "str3"]
str.start_with?(list_of_strs)
```

Comment: Yes `str.start_with?(*list_of_strs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*` to expand the array.

```
str.start_with?(*list_of_strs)
```